# Get the values of distance and timing when throwing a dragged element

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations, physics

I'm wondering how to get the values of distance and timing when the user stops dragging an element.
After a bit of research, I heard about the notions of acceleration and velocity but I'm still confused.

Some examples that illustrate this animation :

- https://codepen.io/osublake/details/jbRaMY
- https://codepen.io/osublake/pen/YrXdGZ
- https://codepen.io/mallendeo/pen/wBJQvp

Here's the kind of situation where I'm stuck at :

```js
let draggableEl = document.getElementById('draggable');
let mousePos = { x: -1, y: -1 };

draggableEl.addEventListener('mousedown', onMousedown);

function onMousedown(e) {
  document.documentElement.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseup);
  document.documentElement.addEventListener('mousemove', updateMousePos);
  updateMousePos(e);
  updateUI();
}

function onMouseup() {
  document.documentElement.removeEventListener('mousemove', updateMousePos);
  mousePos.x = -1;
  mousePos.y = -1;

  // Now how to get the time and throwVal ?
  // draggableEl.style.transition = `transform ${time} ease-out-in`
  // draggableEl.style.transform = `translate(${throwVal.x}, ${throwVal.y})` 
}

function updateMousePos(e) {
  mousePos.x = e.pageX;
  mousePos.y = e.pageY;
}

function updateUI() {
  if (mousePos.x === -1 && mousePos.y === -1)
    return;
  draggableEl.style.transform = `translate( ${mousePos.x}px, ${mousePos.y}px)`;
  requestAnimationFrame(updateUI);
}
```

```css
#draggable {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  cursor: grab;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Drag</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="draggable">Drag me</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you explicitly state what problem you've encountered and what you expect of the solution? This way, answerers can give you a more precise answer.

Comment: I'd like to have a smooth sliding effect when the user releases his drag like on the examples I put in the question. The problem is that I can't find the right values for the `time` and the `throwVal` (distance) to animate my element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calculating the amount of time needed for the draggable element to stop (which involves some relatively complicated physics formula), we can set it so that the draggable element stops after a certain amount of time.

To make it more real, we can use the `cubic-bezier` function. Using it, we can simulate it so that it seems like it's losing speed. We don't have to mimic the way physics work exactly (use illusion).

Here's a working example (with some comments on how it works). I've also modified some code so that the initial `mousedown` event does not move the element.

```js
let draggableEl = document.getElementById('draggable');
let mousePos = { 
  x: -1, 
  y: -1,
  started: false,
  startX: -1,
  startY: -1
};

// Used to track the last UI's transform position after the deceleration
// and also after any dragging
let uiTransform = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};

// Used to simulate UI's deceleration
let uiMotion = {
  oldX: -1,
  oldY: -1,
  x: -1,
  y: -1
};

draggableEl.addEventListener('mousedown', onMousedown);

function onMousedown(e) {
  // Extract the last transform value
  // Necessary because deceleration may be stopped by mousedown
  // before the UI's natural deceleration is finished
  let transformsValue = draggableEl.style.transform.match(/(-?\d*\.?\d+)/g)
  draggableEl.style.transition = 'none'
  uiTransform.x = (transformsValue && parseFloat(transformsValue[0])) || 0
  uiTransform.y = (transformsValue && parseFloat(transformsValue[1])) || 0
  uiTransform.offsetTop // Trigger layout reflow so that transition none is applied
  draggableEl.style.transform = `translate(${uiTransform.x}px, ${uiTransform.y}px)`

  document.documentElement.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseup);
  document.documentElement.addEventListener('mousemove', updateMousePos);
  updateMousePos(e);
  updateUI();
}

function onMouseup() {
  document.documentElement.removeEventListener('mouseup', onMouseup);
  document.documentElement.removeEventListener('mousemove', updateMousePos);
  uiTransform.x += mousePos.x - mousePos.startX
  uiTransform.y += mousePos.y - mousePos.startY

  // The throwVal you asked for
  // Time to decelerate is 1s
  let throwVal = {
    x: (uiMotion.x - uiMotion.oldX) * 3,
    y: (uiMotion.y - uiMotion.oldY) * 3
  }
  draggableEl.style.transition = `transform 1s cubic-bezier(.27,1.04,.61,.97)`
  draggableEl.style.transform = `translate(${uiTransform.x + throwVal.x}px, ${uiTransform.y + throwVal.y}px)`
  
  mousePos.x = -1;
  mousePos.y = -1;
  mousePos.startX = -1;
  mousePos.startY = -1;
  mousePos.started = false;
  
  uiMotion.x = -1
  uiMotion.y = -1
  uiMotion.oldX = -1
  uiMotion.oldY = -1
}

function updateMousePos(e) {
  if (!mousePos.started) {
    mousePos.startX = e.pageX;
    mousePos.startY = e.pageY;
    mousePos.started = true;
  }
  mousePos.x = e.pageX;
  mousePos.y = e.pageY;
}

function updateUI() {
  if (mousePos.x === -1 && mousePos.y === -1)
    return;
  // Fixed some code
  let xValue = uiTransform.x + mousePos.x - mousePos.startX
  let yValue = uiTransform.y + mousePos.y - mousePos.startY
  draggableEl.style.transform = `translate(${xValue}px, ${yValue}px)`;
  
  if (uiMotion.oldX === -1 && uiMotion.oldY === -1) {
    uiMotion.oldX = xValue
    uiMotion.oldY = yValue
  } else {
    if (uiMotion.x !== -1 && uiMotion.y !== -1) {
      uiMotion.oldX = uiMotion.x
      uiMotion.oldY = uiMotion.y
    }
    uiMotion.x = xValue
    uiMotion.y = yValue
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(updateUI);
}
```

```css
html {
background: #121212;}

#draggable {
  position: absolute;
  background: #585858;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: grab;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Drag</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="draggable"></div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow, huge thanks! Your answer really helps me to understand it.